# How do I calculate the distance between the marks on the picture above as pixels on wolfram mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

[image]

How do I calculate the distance between the marks on the picture above as pixels on wolfram mathematica?

Comment: right click and use get coordinates.

Comment: I don't need coordinates. I want to measure the distance between marks as pixels

Comment: distance is `Sqrt[(x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2]`.   Maybe you should work a little harder at explaining what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pts = x /. Solve[{Sin[x] == 0, 10 <= x <= 20}, x];

plot = Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 10, 20}],
   ListPlot[Transpose[{pts, ConstantArray[0, Length[pts]]}],
    PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.01]}]];

partitions = Partition[Union[Last /@
     Position[ImageData[plot], {1., 0., 0., 1.}, Infinity]], 2, 1];

xpos = Append[First /@ Select[partitions, #[[2]] - #[[1]] > 1 &],
   partitions[[-1, -1]]];

Differences[xpos]
```

> {103, 104}

The first pair of points are 103 pixels apart and the next pair are 104 pixels apart.